# Regular Expression for phone numbers in android

Tags: android, regex

I am trying to validate my phone number that are entered on textbox. This is the format that comes up:

```
+919876453210
```

So I tried the following regular exp:

```
^\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$
```

But this validates if I enter only 12 number too? can somebody help me fix the phone number format validation?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: @DerGolem - Thanks for the help but this link couldn't help me. I have already seen them.

Comment: What must match and what mustn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's it

```
 ^\+[0-9]{6,12}$
  ^\+[0-9]{MIN_DIGITS_COUNT,MAX_DIGITS_COUNT}$
```

Comment: @TheDevMan actually i don't know exactly, probably because of question mark and colon.